# extracting a tuple from a dictionary with a key/tuple pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I know I'm close:

```
    for k in my_dictionary:
        #print (k, my_dict[k][0],my_dict[k][1])
        for v in my_dict[k]:
            print (v,my_dict[k])
```

results in:

```
tuple00('tuple00','tuple01')
tuple01('tuple00','tuple01')
tuple10('tuple10','tuple11')
tuple11('tuple10','tuple11')
```

The commented line will give me a better result

```
key0 tuple00 tuple01
key1 tuple00 tuple01
```

but I have to address them by the:

```
my_dict[k][0],my_dict[k][1]
```

which is ugly. Doing:

```
    for k in my_dict:
        for i,m in k:
            print (i,m,k)
```

gives as error in:

```
    for i,m in k:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I know that a list comprehension is probably what I'm after, but I still can't even begin to grasp that.

I would accept an answer through loops (as above) or dict/list comprehension...

What I really want though, is to be able to select a `Key` value and use the tuple as a referenced pair: `i` and `m`

Comment: What you want is probably: `for key, value in my_dict.iteritems()`

Comment: `iteritems` not available: I got an error for `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: In python 3 just use `my_dict.items()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unpack using `.items`:

```
 d = {"key":("v1","v2")}

for k, (v1, v2) in d.items():
    print(k, v1, v2)
```

Which would print:

```
('key', 'v1', 'v2')
```

Using `(v1, v2)` unpacks each `tuple/value`.

Comment: You know, I was SURE I tried this. But this has hit the nail on the head! :)

Comment: Wrapping in  `()` is the key, without it you would be trying to unpack three elements  which would give you  the old `need more than 2 values to unpack`.

Comment: Thanks again, it's had me stumped for hours... NOW I can go to bed :)

Comment: No worries, I  know the feeling ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
d = {"key":("v1","v2")}

for key in d:
    print((key,) + d[key])
```

Unpacks to:

```
('key', 'v1', 'v2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
    for key, value in dictd.iteritems():
        print key, value[0], value[1]
```

Comment: it was the ugliness of the indexes I wanted to get rid of (more for readability and my OCD) :)

Comment: I also did get an error for `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`